# Character unable to dash NorthEast but can dash in other directions, including NorthWest

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the function below on a character controller to Dash in my 2d platformer. For some reason I can dash East, West, North, and NorthWest but not NorthEast, and I can't figure out the issue.  I'm sure it's got to be an issue with my math equation used for DashDir but I'm not sure where I went wrong.  Facing is simply an Enum holding -1 or 1.  Any advice would be helpful - Ideally I'd actually like to be able to dash all 8 directions.

```
private IEnumerator Dash_Enter () {
    dashCooldownTimer = DashCooldown;
    Speed = Vector2.zero;
    DashDir = Vector2.zero;

    Vector2 value = new Vector2(moveX, moveY);
    if (value == Vector2.zero) {
        value = new Vector2 ((int)Facing, 0f);
    } else if (value.x == 0 && value.y > 0 && onGround) {
        value = new Vector2 ((int)Facing, value.y);
    }
    value.Normalize();
    Vector2 vector = value * DashSpeed;
    Speed = vector;
    DashDir = value;
    if (DashDir.x != 0f) {
        Facing = (Facings)Mathf.Sign (DashDir.x);
    }
    if (DashDir.y < 0 && onGround) {
        DashDir.y = 0;
        DashDir.x = Mathf.Sign (DashDir.x);
        Speed.y = 0f;
        Speed.x *= 2f;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (DashTime);

    // Wait one extra frame
    yield return null;

    if (DashDir.y >= 0f) {
        Speed = DashDir * EndDashSpeed;
    }
    if (Speed.y > 0f) {
        Speed.y = Speed.y * EndDashUpMult;

    }
    fsm.ChangeState (States.Normal, StateTransition.Overwrite);
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: As DashDir is always positive, is this not the cause of your troubles

Comment: How is Facing being assigned to prior to Dash_Enter being called and how is your Facings enum defined?